# allocaton of memory

Tags: c

```
node *getnode()
    {
        node *x;
        x = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (x==NULL)
            {
                    printf("no memory \n");
                    exit(1);
            }
        return x;
    }


*insert_rear(int item ,node *first)
    {
        node  *temp;
        node  *cur;
        temp = getnode();


        temp -> data = item;
        temp -> next = NULL;

        if (first == NULL)
        return temp;

        cur = first;
        while(cur -> next != NULL)
          {
            cur = cur -> next;
          }

        cur -> next = temp;
        return first;
    }
```

in insert_rear when the function calls getnode it goes to the above function, and it creates a node, while debugging using gdb when i did

```
(gdb) p temp
$7 = (struct classifier *) 0x8d8f080
(gdb) p &temp
$8 = (struct classifier **) 0xbff9cb04
```

what is the difference between the two.

Comment: Have you considered taking a programming course, or even hiring a tutor? I'm serious, because you have asked quite a few very basic questions over a long period of time.

Answer (score 3):

In the

```
p &temp
```

you are printing the stack address for the variable temp.
With

```
p temp
```

you are printing the value of temp (which is the address of the allocated memory returned by getnode()

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple indirections:
`temp` has received a pointer address from `getnode()` that points to a node memory allocated by `malloc`.

`&temp` is the address of the memory that store this address (that points to the node).

Basically you have

```
&temp ---(points to)---> Memory X ***temp*** ---(points to)---> Memory Y ****MEMORY from malloc of "type" node****
```

So if you use `*temp` you are accessing the node. And if you are using `*(&temp)` (don't know if it's valid syntax...) but you would be accessing `temp` which stores the address where the node is stored.

Comment: `*&temp` is legal syntax, as is `&*temp`.